# Elimination matrix (Gauss) in python

Tags: python, list, function, matrix

I'm trying to code a gauss-jordan elimination code without the use of numpy, I'm pretty much done, I know the first part works for sure but the 2 before last lines aren't working and I can't figure out why. The output I need is:

```
[[12,0,0,1,13,-9],[0,2.66667,0,-2,-29,20],[0,0,-0.09375,1,15.6667,-10.6667]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def gauss_jordan():

    a = [[12, 7, 3, 1, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0], [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 1]]

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i][i] == 0.0:
            sys.exit('Divide by zero detected!')  
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if i != j:
                ratio = a[j][i]/a[i][i]
                for k in range(len(a[0])):
                    a[j][k] = a[j][k] - ratio * a[i][k]

    #These next 2 lines need fixing  
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = (a[i][len(a)]/a[i][i])        

    return a
```

Edit: Here is my updated code that gives me the generator error:

'''

def gauss_jordan():

```
a = [[12, 7, 3, 1, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0], [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 1]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][i] == 0.0:
        sys.exit('Divide by zero detected!')  
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i != j:
            ratio = a[j][i]/a[i][i]
            for k in range(len(a[0])):
                a[j][k] = a[j][k] - ratio * a[i][k]

#These next 2 lines need fixing  
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = (v/a[i][i] for v in a[i])        

return a
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines should be:

```
for i in range(len(a)): 
    a[i] = [v/a[i][i] for v in a[i]]
```

General advise: it is helpful to use meaningful names for variables, like row, column etc.

UPD: since there is something sketchy with the platform, try this:

```
for row in range(len(a)): 
    ratio = a[row][row]
    for col in range(len(a[0]):
        a[row][col] /= ratio
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives this as an output: [<generator object gauss_jordan.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f8bf6ac1250>, <generator object gauss_jordan.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f8bf6ac12d0>, <generator object gauss_jordan.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f8bf6ac13d0>]

Comment: @agg199 it means something went wrong before this part. Check the content of `a` just before this fragment

Comment: the content of a right before the fragment is good, it's: [[12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.000000000000215, 156.00000000000293, -108.00000000000203], [0.0, 2.666666666666667, 0.0, -5.33333333333344, -77.33333333333479, 53.333333333334345], [0.0, 0.0, -0.09374999999999822, -0.09375000000000022, -1.4687499999999996, 1.0]]

Comment: @agg199 I can run it without any problem. Did you replace square brackets with parenthesis?

Comment: No I really just copy pasted what you wrote into my function

Comment: I added the code I'm running right now as an edit on my initial post

Comment: @agg199 yes, I just confirmed running the whole code and it works. The only reasonable explanation was the replacement of a list comprehension with a generator expression; so it is something really weird, like running it on an exotic platform like pypy. Please see the update for an alternative solution

Comment: That works! thanks so much, it sucks that the other one isn't working for me since it is more concise

Comment: actually I just realized the output is: [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.000000000000018, 13.000000000000243, -9.000000000000169], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -2.0000000000000395, -29.000000000000544, 20.000000000000377], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 1.0000000000000213, 15.66666666666696, -10.666666666666869]] which is not the output I need

Comment: @agg199 the result of gauss jordan elimination is expected to have diagonal ones, and this is what the last few lines are in fact doing. The desired output in the question does not match the nature of the task

Comment: Yes however that is the output I'm expected to get, is there any way to get that with a different modification of the 2 before last lines?